Do I put GoBoard over the lip of the tub or on top of the lip?
I recently had to replace the plumbing for my old bathtub and got a new bathtub in the process. The new tub is this Kohler Ensemble model.
For the backing board I've decided to go with GoBoard, but regardless of the material I've seen conflicting opinions in the YouTube install videos I've watched. Some say you always put the backing board above the lip and others say need to go over the lip.
Attached is a picture of my bathtub which is attached to the studs. Based off the look of it, I believe I should put the GoBoard over the lip that way it covers the metal clips? It also has those little divets where you could attach the plastic walls that come with an additional kit you could purchase, but I'm using tile - not the pre-fabed plastic walls. My assumption is because of those metal clips and the divets the GoBoard would go over the lip and I'd leave about an 1/8 inch gap at the bottom to fill in with caulk. Then apply thinset and tiles over all that to have a nice plumb wall. Is my assumption correct?
If not, and I'm supposed to install the GoBoard above the lip, do I just apply thinset over the metal clip? That just doesn't seem like it would yield a very clean and level result to me...


Any sheathing goes over the lip to start a properly sealed tub enclosure.

How would I adjust for the gap that will be caused by the lip and the metal clip then? It will cause the bottom to be further out than the top part of the wall by at least an 1/8 inch. Won't that cause problems with the tile?

@Narm, No, the difference is unnoticeable once the tile is installed.  Just don't place screws directly above the lip. Make the attachment point of the first screw  about  4 inches above the  lip.

Can't you just notch out the bottom of the GoBoard for the clip?  Also, that screw is driven crooked.

The screw is inconsequential.  Also the perception of the board needing to be perfectly plumb is wrong.  The wood studs will have dips, twists and bows that make the board less than perfectly plumb or flat.  that is why the slight change to the flat surface of the board, once installed, does not matter. These changes are mitigated with the tile installation. Any unevenness remaining is not noticeable without a mechanical means of measurement.
